Creating a table with percentages of one variable
I would like to make a table that looks like the attached image in Markdown 
The variable I'm looking to report on is happiness. The survey question asked people whether they are very happy, happy, neutral, unhappy or very unhappy.  I'd like to see the percentage of people who report being 'very happy' and 'happy'. I have created a new variable/column where every person who has reported being very happy or happy is marked has a value of 1 in that column, and 0 if they are neutral, unhappy or very unhappy.
My dataframe has a variable for gender, where 1 = male, 2 = female and 3 = non-binary. I also have a variable for age group where those aged 18-24 = 1, 25-44 = 2, 45-64 = 3 and those aged 65+ have a value of 4.
An example of what my dataframe looks like: 
How can I create a table with the relevant percentages in column 2, add in the correct n values in the first column, and also perform a significance test for each of my categories (gender and age group)?
I have tried Mat Statter's approach and have the following table output:

I'm not sure why the P-values are coming up as 1 and are not appearing for each level of the variable - i.e. female, male and non-binary?

If you want your table to look exactly like that, you will likely have to piece it together yourself.
If you want something similar, the {table1} package has a nice function called table1().
library(table1)

set.seed(42)

data <- data.frame(
  Age = sample(c("18-24", "25-44", "45-64", "65+"), 100, replace = TRUE),
  Gender = sample(c("Male", "Female", "Non-binary"), 100, replace = TRUE),
  Happiness = sample(c("Not Happy", "Happy"), 100, replace = TRUE)
)

pvalue <- function(x, ...) {
  # remove all but happy column for chi-square goodness of fit test
  x$overall <- NULL
  x$`Not Happy` <- NULL
  
  y <- unlist(x)
  g <- factor(rep(1:length(x), times=sapply(x, length)))
  p <- chisq.test(table(y, g))$p.value
  c("", sub("<", "&lt;", format.pval(p, digits=3, eps=0.001)))
}

table1(
  ~ Age + Gender | Happiness, 
  data = data, 
  extra.col = list(`P-value` = pvalue)
)



Thank you so much for your answer! I had tried making a demographics table using the tableone package where it stratified based on happiness. I also have other variables with only 2 levels, and unfortunately it does not display both levels, it only displays one, unless there are more than 2 levels. Hopefully table1 will be a better option!
Unfortunately I'm getting this error: Error in as.data.frame.default(data, optional = TRUE) :
cannot coerce class ‘"function"’ to a data.frame

Additionally, it looks like it is calculating p values between happy and not happy - is it possible to calculate between happy age groups instead?

Not sure about your error. You may need to open another question with details about that. But you are correct that the p-values were from chi-square tests of independence comparing a demographic to happiness status. I've edited the example to preform a chi-square goodness of fit test for each demographic using the happy column.

Thanks Mad Statter! I've been looking around for a way to fix my error, however no luck yet so I will post a different question, thanks for your help, looking forward to seeing the table once the error is solved.

Hi @the-mad-statter I've just edited my post with a screenshot of the output. I'm not sure why the P-values are coming up as 1 and are not appearing for each level of the variable - i.e. female, male and non-binary?

Make sure you are removing the overall column in pvalue(). Otherwise, the overall numbers get included and you would be performing a test of independence (i.e., matrix(c(493, 1525, 1398, 781, 493, 1525, 1398, 781), ncol = 2) |> chisq.test()) as opposed to a goodness of fit test as desired. In my code that is this line: x$overall <- NULL. There is only one p-value because there is only one test: a goodness of fit comparing the count per level across all levels for each variable.

Thank you! I'm very grateful for your help in this. I suppose I'm wondering if there is a way to conduct a p test for each level (male, female, non-binary) to see if each level is associated with happiness, rather than just the gender variable overall? I'd love to be able to report that for example, females and happiness had a p value of <0.001 and while for males there was no significant association etc. Your first comment said I would need to piece something like this together myself, do you know of any additional hints that might help me with this particular quest?

See my second answer which shows a way to calculate the p-value from an exact binomial test with alternative hypothesis: true probability of being happy is not equal to 0.5 in each level of your factors.

library(table1)

set.seed(42)

data <- data.frame(
  Age = sample(c("18-24", "25-44", "45-64", "65+"), 100, replace = TRUE),
  Gender = sample(c("Male", "Female", "Non-binary"), 100, replace = TRUE),
  Happiness = sample(c("Not Happy", "Happy"), 100, replace = TRUE)
)

pvalue <- function(x, ...) {
  levels <- levels(x$Happy)
  p <- vapply(
    seq_along(levels), 
    \(l) {
      n <- sum(x$Happy == levels[l])
      N <- sum(x$overall == levels[l])
      binom.test(n, N)$p.value
    }, 
    numeric(1)
  )
  c("", sub("<", "&lt;", format.pval(p, digits=3, eps=0.001)))
}

table1(
  ~ Age + Gender | Happiness, 
  data = data, 
  extra.col = list(`P-value` = pvalue)
)


